# Extension method not being recognized

Tags: vb.net, razor, extension-methods

I've got a web application project in VB.NET and am trying to add an extension method for use in in a view.

**Extensions.vb**

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices    
Namespace MyApp
    Public Module Extensions
        <Extension()> _
            Public Function GetValOrDefault(ByVal dict As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByVal key As String, ByVal defaultVal As String) As String
                    Dim val As String
                    If (dict.TryGetValue(key, val)) Then
                        Return val
                    End If
                Return defaultVal
            End Function
        End Module
End Namespace
```

**View.cshtml**

```
@Code
    Dim msgs As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    msgs("Foo") = "Bar"
    Dim val As String = msgs.GetValOrDefault("Foo", "Bar")
End Code
```

However, this doesn't work, showing the following error:

```
'GetValOrDefault' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)'.
```

This is a fairly straightforward extension method, and I'm not sure why it's not being picked up.  Also tried adding an even simpler extension taking just a string and returning a string, with the same problem, so it seems like the extension methods aren't being picked up.

Tried compiling, also with no luck.  Note, the module is in the same project as the view, but I don't think that should make any difference (I've done this in C# projects with no problems).

Is there a step or something else I'm missing that needs to be done to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, but, in case others are also scratching their heads, make sure you check that the Build Action of the file containing the extension is set to Compile. After two hours of going quietly insane and wondering why the extension only worked in certain places, I realised it was set to Content.  A quick change to Compile and it worked. :)

Comment: Or be like me and only build the Debug version of your lib, but your main is importing the Release version. =(

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the namespace "MyApp" in your web.config within the views folder?

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MyApp"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Note: After adding to your web.config you may have to close and re-open your view to have the extension be available with Intellisense.

The other option is to import your MyApp namespace directly into the view: `@Import MyApp`

Comment: Tried it, no difference.  Extension method still not being picked up.

Comment: I don't use VB.net very often. What is the underscore after the <Extension()> attribute for?

Comment: Also, your extension has 2 parameters and you are only supplying one.

Comment: its for line continuation, to help the cleanliness of the code so you do have a super long line of code across the screen

Comment: @Sam Same here, C# is my language of choice.  The underscore is usually to join lines, but doesn't make much of a difference here.  Second parameter missing was just an error in the code copied to the question.

Comment: If that's not it, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Sam Yea, I think there's something else funky going on with this project (inherited codebase).  Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the type for the extension. I just tried it with no problems.

```
Public Module Extensions
 <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
 Public Function GetValOrDefault(Of dict As Dictionary(Of String, String))(ByVal d As dict, ByVal key As String, ByVal defaultVal As String) As String
  Dim val As String = ""
  If (d.TryGetValue(key, val)) Then
   Return val
  End If
  Return defaultVal
 End Function
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this was because my extension method relied on a reference that my calling project didn't contain.

This was made visible by calling the method statically which caused vs to bring up the error. Referencing the required dll fixed the issue and allowed me to call it as an extension.